# how do you do a buffer analysis of a geographical location?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, buffer

I want to use a buffer analysis to identify the geodemographics of Incinerators. I have downloaded the Output Area Classification (OAC) map and also know the locations of all the Incinerators I want to analyse from an online map. I want to know how i can perform a buffer analysis from the geographical point in which the Incinerators are located based on the OAC map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm missing something, but it seems that all you need here is your point shapefile and the buffer tool which is located at: Analysis Tools -> Proximity -> Buffer

Specify your input points and a buffer distance. Use the "Show Help" pane in the tool if you need guidance on some of the tool options.

Comment: ok so shall i create a point shapefile for the locations of the incinerators?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create a shapefile of these locations. You can create the shapefile from a spreadsheet that has your x,y coordinates using ArcCatalog. Browse to the folder where the spreadsheet resides and right-click and choose from the options that appear to create a shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can also open these in python as points and simply loop through them, buffering each one.  It's a very simple bit of code to do them all.